# How do I check if a number is bigger than all other numbers to the right of it in array

Tags: java

For example I have an array of these values

> [10, 14, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8, 0]

If I start with 10 it would be bigger than 2, 1, 5, 7, 8, and 0. Then 14 would be bigger than 2, 1, 5, 7, 8, and 0 and so on.

Is there a way I can loop through a certain array and find the total count of smaller numbers moving from left to right?

Here is what I have tried:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        if(array[i] > array[j]) {
            count++;
    }
}
```

Using

> [10, 14, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8, 0]

I expect the output of `18`, but the actual output is `1`.

Comment: What do you mean by "and so on"? `2` is *smaller* than all the numbers following. And why is the expected result 18? What are you counting and adding?

Comment: How your expected output is `18` can you elaborate more ?

Comment: I think he wants to take 10, compare them to each number to the right, and add 1 if 10 is greater than the compared number, and then do 14, and so on. Gives 18.

Comment: I am trying to find the total count of numbers to the right of a specific value that are smaller than that value. So the count starting from 10 would be 6(10 is bigger than 2, 1, 5, 7, 8 and 0), then the count from 14 would be 6, and the count from 2 would be 2.

Comment: Could you please add definition of array variable as well. Is it a matrix? If not, then array[i].length must throw an exception.

Comment: @yasuomainbtw why `array[i].length` ??? shoudl be rather `array.length` unless you got 2 d array, but if so - rest is bad.

Comment: Make sure you initialize your counter to 0 before the loops. I guess `j < array[i].length` for the second loop is a typo. Should be `j < array.length`

Comment: This code looks legit to me. Problem must be somewere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want total no of smaller elements in the array moving from right to left. If so Here is a solution.

Here is your array.
[10, 14, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8, 0]

```
int[] countArray= new int[array.length];
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int count=0;
    for(int j = i + 1; j < array.length-1; j++) {
        if(array[i] > array[j]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    countArray[i]=count;
}
```

Comment: Now im lost. That at any point will not give you 18 as required (*I expect the output of 18, but the actual output is 1.*). Moreover - code that OP passed in actuall works as required. But yet this is accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right:

```
int count = 0;
int[] array = {10, 14, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8, 0};

for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[i] > array[j]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You got an error in second loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < array[i].length; j++) { // HERE is mistake, array.length
        if(array[i] > array[j]) {
            count++;
    }
}
```

on the other hand I am wondering how that does even compile...

Answer (score 1):

The first loop should work array.lenth-1 times, the other way also will give true answer.

```
    int count = 0;
    int[] array = new int[]{ 10, 14, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8, 0 };
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: TBH it does not matter as array.length+1 will not be  < array.length so nor problem with that - inner for will just not fire.

Comment: @Antoniossss It would work 1 more time unnecessarily, just that.

Comment: Obviously - still does not matter- its neglectable.

Comment: @Antoniossss Yet it does not matter, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is runing code

```
public class Teas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = {
            10,
            14,
            2,
            1,
            5,
            7,
            8,
            0
        };
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

Your Logic is correct I think count variable initialization is wrong.
you might initializing in for loop